# Mapquest Static Map POIs Do Not Show Labels

Tags: maps, marker, mapquest

I am new to mapping and have tried Google Maps and Bing Maps before choosing Mapquest for its developer friendly API.

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 database that creates a static map with many POIs. The data is for Metropolitan Statistical Areas and indicates city real estate markets within each region. Each city is referenced by Lat/Long coordinates. Ideally I need to send a URL for each row in the recordset, with POIs sequentially numbered (1-150+) and enable infoboxes to popup when a POI marker on click or mouseover. The infobox contains market data for that POI.

Despite days of working through API documentation I am not able to display more than the first label ("1") or the specified colors. Is there a parameter that I am missing? My code is below as is a screenshot.

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd%7Cluub20ual1%2C8g%3Do5-9ur216&size=770,770&zoom=2&type=hyb&imagetype=jpeg&pois=green-1,34.12,-118.76|pois=green-2,34.2,-118.13|pois=green-3,34.17,-117.87|pois=green-4,34.09,-117.96|pois=green-5,33.97,-118.15|pois=green-6,34.11,-118.67|pois=green-7,34.19,-118.6|pois=green-8,34.43,-118.46|pois=red-9,34.51,-118.68|pois=green-10,33.86,-118.05|pois=green-11,34.09,-117.9|pois=green-12,33.99,-118.39|pois=green-13,33.99,-117.81|pois=red-14,34.14,-117.96|pois=green-15,34.08,-118.03|pois=green-16,33.91,-118.4|pois=green-17,33.89,-118.29|pois=green-18,34.29,-118.5|pois=green-19,34,-117.97|pois=red-20,33.79,-118.29|pois=green-21,33.83,-118.07|pois=red-22,33.86,-118.39|pois=green-23,33.97,-118.21|pois=red-24,33.95,-118.36|pois=red-25,34.23,-118.14|pois=green-26,34.23,-118.24|pois=green-27,33.89,-118|pois=green-28,34.02,-117.93|pois=green-29,34.15,-117.76|pois=red-30,34.69,-118.52|pois=green-31,34.48,-117.92|pois=red-32,33.79,-118.31|pois=green-33,33.97,-118.24|pois=green-34,33.92,-118.2|pois=red-35,34.03,-118.7|pois=green-36,33.88,-118.4|pois=green-37,33.97,-118.43|pois=green-38,34.27,-118.45|pois=green-39,34.05,-118.14|pois=green-40,34.23,-118.47|pois=green-41,34.16,-118.37|pois=green-42,34.24,-118.55|pois=green-43,34.07,-118.54|pois=green-44,34.25,-118.41|pois=green-45,34.22,-118.44|pois=green-46,33.89,-118.16|pois=green-47,34.48,-117.88|pois=green-48,33.98,-118.08|pois=green-49,33.94,-118.44|pois=green-50,33.75,-118.31|pois=green-51,33.83,-118.38|pois=green-52,34.2,-118.54|pois=green-53,34.06,-118.08|pois=green-54,33.97,-117.9|pois=green-55,34.1,-117.81|pois=green-56,34.28,-118.44|pois=green-57,34.11,-118.08|pois=green-58,34.12,-118.11|pois=green-59,33.73,-118.29|pois=green-60,34.43,-118.51|pois=green-61,33.92,-118.06|pois=green-62,34.01,-118.49|pois=green-63,34.14,-118.46|pois=green-64,34.2,-118.05|pois=red-65,34.04,-118.04|pois=green-66,33.94,-118.2|`
```

[Example Map](http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd%7Cluub20ual1,8g=o5-9ur216&size=770,770&zoom=2&type=hyb&imagetype=jpeg&pois=green-1,34.12,-118.76%7Cpois=green-2,34.2,-118.13%7Cpois=green-3,34.17,-117.87%7Cpois=green-4,34.09,-117.96%7Cpois=green-5,33.97,-118.15%7Cpois=green-6,34.11,-118.67%7Cpois=green-7,34.19,-118.6%7Cpois=green-8,34.43,-118.46%7Cpois=red-9,34.51,-118.68%7Cpois=green-10,33.86,-118.05%7Cpois=green-11,34.09,-117.9%7Cpois=green-12,33.99,-118.39%7Cpois=green-13,33.99,-117.81%7Cpois=red-14,34.14,-117.96%7Cpois=green-15,34.08,-118.03%7Cpois=green-16,33.91,-118.4%7Cpois=green-17,33.89,-118.29%7Cpois=green-18,34.29,-118.5%7Cpois=green-19,34,-117.97%7Cpois=red-20,33.79,-118.29%7Cpois=green-21,33.83,-118.07%7Cpois=red-22,33.86,-118.39%7Cpois=green-23,33.97,-118.21%7Cpois=red-24,33.95,-118.36%7Cpois=red-25,34.23,-118.14%7Cpois=green-26,34.23,-118.24%7Cpois=green-27,33.89,-118%7Cpois=green-28,34.02,-117.93%7Cpois=green-29,34.15,-117.76%7Cpois=red-30,34.69,-118.52%7Cpois=green-31,34.48,-117.92%7Cpois=red-32,33.79,-118.31%7Cpois=green-33,33.97,-118.24%7Cpois=green-34,33.92,-118.2%7Cpois=red-35,34.03,-118.7%7Cpois=green-36,33.88,-118.4%7Cpois=green-37,33.97,-118.43%7Cpois=green-38,34.27,-118.45%7Cpois=green-39,34.05,-118.14%7Cpois=green-40,34.23,-118.47%7Cpois=green-41,34.16,-118.37%7Cpois=green-42,34.24,-118.55%7Cpois=green-43,34.07,-118.54%7Cpois=green-44,34.25,-118.41%7Cpois=green-45,34.22,-118.44%7Cpois=green-46,33.89,-118.16%7Cpois=green-47,34.48,-117.88%7Cpois=green-48,33.98,-118.08%7Cpois=green-49,33.94,-118.44%7Cpois=green-50,33.75,-118.31%7Cpois=green-51,33.83,-118.38%7Cpois=green-52,34.2,-118.54%7Cpois=green-53,34.06,-118.08%7Cpois=green-54,33.97,-117.9%7Cpois=green-55,34.1,-117.81%7Cpois=green-56,34.28,-118.44%7Cpois=green-57,34.11,-118.08%7Cpois=green-58,34.12,-118.11%7Cpois=green-59,33.73,-118.29%7Cpois=green-60,34.43,-118.51%7Cpois=green-61,33.92,-118.06%7Cpois=green-62,34.01,-118.49%7Cpois=green-63,34.14,-118.46%7Cpois=green-64,34.2,-118.05%7Cpois=red-65,34.04,-118.04%7Cpois=green-66,33.94,-118.2%7C)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at MapQuest.

It looks like you are adding extra parameters to the call which may be causing the service to ignore the numbering that you have assigned to each poi.  Also, we do not offer red icons that are the same style as the green icons that you are placing on the map.  Here is an example of your request using orange pois instead of red, since we offer blue, orange, green, purple, white, and yellow in that style:

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd%7Cluub20ual1%2C8g%3Do5-9ur216&size=770,770&zoom=2&type=hyb&imagetype=jpeg&pois=green-1,34.12,-118.76|green-2,34.2,-118.13|green-3,34.17,-117.87|green-4,34.09,-117.96|green-5,33.97,-118.15|green-6,34.11,-118.67|green-7,34.19,-118.6|green-8,34.43,-118.46|yellow-9,34.51,-118.68|green-10,33.86,-118.05|green-11,34.09,-117.9|green-12,33.99,-118.39|green-13,33.99,-117.81|yellow-14,34.14,-117.96|green-15,34.08,-118.03|green-16,33.91,-118.4|green-17,33.89,-118.29|green-18,34.29,-118.5|green-19,34,-117.97|yellow-20,33.79,-118.29|green-21,33.83,-118.07|yellow-22,33.86,-118.39|green-23,33.97,-118.21|yellow-24,33.95,-118.36|yellow-25,34.23,-118.14|green-26,34.23,-118.24|green-27,33.89,-118|green-28,34.02,-117.93|green-29,34.15,-117.76|yellow-30,34.69,-118.52|green-31,34.48,-117.92|yellow-32,33.79,-118.31|green-33,33.97,-118.24|green-34,33.92,-118.2|yellow-35,34.03,-118.7|green-36,33.88,-118.4|green-37,33.97,-118.43|green-38,34.27,-118.45|green-39,34.05,-118.14|green-40,34.23,-118.47|green-41,34.16,-118.37|green-42,34.24,-118.55|green-43,34.07,-118.54|green-44,34.25,-118.41|green-45,34.22,-118.44|green-46,33.89,-118.16|green-47,34.48,-117.88|green-48,33.98,-118.08|green-49,33.94,-118.44|green-50,33.75,-118.31|green-51,33.83,-118.38|green-52,34.2,-118.54|green-53,34.06,-118.08|green-54,33.97,-117.9|green-55,34.1,-117.81|green-56,34.28,-118.44|green-57,34.11,-118.08|green-58,34.12,-118.11|green-59,33.73,-118.29|green-60,34.43,-118.51|green-61,33.92,-118.06|green-62,34.01,-118.49|green-63,34.14,-118.46|green-64,34.2,-118.05|yellow-65,34.04,-118.04|green-66,33.94,-118.2
```

More information about styles of pois offered through the Static Maps API is [here](http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/icons.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, red_1 and red_2 are supported.  They are regular, pin-shaped markers and not the callout style that you are currently using. Unfortunately, red is not supported in the callout marker style.